# Enable Logging for opened & closed Connection in Apache/mod_proxy_wstunnel

Tags: apache, logging, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-wstunnel

I'm using an Apache server with a Websocket Reverse Proxy (proxy_wstunnel).

Is there an opportunity to create a log entry for opening and **closing** a websocket connection?

Comment: i'd be interested to know how to do this too